# ListSelectionListener double click

Tags: java, swing, double-click

For a school project I have to use a ListSelectionListener(LSL) on a JList. I know that an LSL responds to a mouse click and a mouse release. But for the project, i have to let it respond to a double click. Is there anyway to make an LSL respond to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a `ListActionHandler` is since you haven't provided the code for it.

My guess is that it implements `MouseListener`, or maybe extends `MouseAdapter`.  If so, there will be a method called `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` that you'll have to implement.  In there, just put an if-check to only respond to double-clicks:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
    // do your stuff here
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you've corrected your post to a `ListSelectionListener`, you'll notice that there is only one method to implement, `void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)` which does not directly translate to mouse clicks.

Why? Because the mouse isn't the only way to change selection on a JList.  It can be done via the arrow keys, or programmatically.

This can be (sort of) solved by adding a `MouseListener` to the JList and then implementing the click count code I've shown.  However, most would consider this a hack since using MouseListeners to track changes in a JList's selection is not advised for reasons already mentioned.

Comment: I tried removing the ListSelectionListener and i'm now using the MouseLustener. As far as I know, it's working perfectly!
Thanks!